# How to echo this multidimensional collection in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, laravel-5.7

first time here, been a lurker and search a lot, but this time having issue with `Laravel` collection. Trying to echo in `foreach`  for this multidimensional collection array, but i have no idea how.

I've tried changing a lot of ways to display that I know of. but to no avail, hope to get some insight to probably change my method or something.. .

The code to get from database

```
$l = [];
for($i = 0; $i < count($request->products); $i++){
    $l[] = [
          'locaction_id' => $request->products[$i]['location'],
        ];
    $locations[] = DB::table('locations')->select('*')->whereIn('location_id',$l)->get();
};
```

The code use to display the arrays, tried both `$location->stuff` and `$location[0][0]['location_id']` come out error

`$location->location_id`, output error:

> unable to find location_id.

`$location[0][0]['location_id']` and `$location['location_id']` give out:

> StdClass error or cannot find location_id.

```
foreach($locations as $key => $location){
   echo $key. "&nbsp; -" .$location->location_id. "<br>";
};
```

The array return from database

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => Collection {#662 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
      0 => {#660 ▼
        +"location_id": 1
        +"loc_name": "A0001"
        +"loc_desc": "Cabinet A North"
        +"created_at": "2019-07-05 10:31:12"
        +"updated_at": null
      }
    ]
  }
  1 => Collection {#688 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
      0 => {#686 ▼
        +"location_id": 1
        +"loc_name": "A0001"
        +"loc_desc": "Cabinet A North"
        +"created_at": "2019-07-05 10:31:12"
        +"updated_at": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Well hoping it get to produce loop results for each arrays.

Comment: If it is `collection` did you try to do: `$location[0]->get(0)->location_id`?

Comment: You may be better off creating your `$location` array as an array of records, at the moment it's an array of collections (which has an array in it).

Comment: @dWinder oh thanks, i tried that but i get "Call to undefined method stdClass::get()"

Comment: Can you please add the `var_dump` of `$locations` (after the loop)?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your approach like this,

```
// first fetch all location ids in array
$locationIds = array_column($request->products, "location");
// pass all location ids to fetch data
$locations   = DB::table('locations')->select('*')->whereIn('location_id', $locationIds)->get();
// do foreach loop to fetch that data
foreach($locations as $key => $location){
   echo $key. "&nbsp; -" .$location->location_id. "<br>";
}
```

If for some reason you are writing your snippet,

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->products); $i++) {
    $l           = $request->products[$i]['location'];
    // I change it to first instead of get
    $locations[] = DB::table('locations')->select('*')->where('location_id', $l)->first();
}
// do foreach loop to fetch that data
foreach ($locations as $key => $location) {
    echo $key . "&nbsp; -" . $location->location_id . "<br>";
}
```